# ServiceBus reciever is not throwing exception after ServiceBus Connection string Refresh and is able to process messages

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-keyvault, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a service-bus receiver instance running as a continuous running webjob, and there is requirement to Refresh the primary connection string 6 months once

what I learnt was if i am refreshing the connection string using azure portal then the existing receiver instance should throw unauthorized exception, but to my surprise its not throwing any exception it runs for 20 min or so and stops receiving message without any exception.

**My Question here is that without getting the exception I cannot hit the key vault and create new instance of the receiver, is there any other alternative way for doing this ?**

I have create a prototype of my application and the service bus package I am using is 
**WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 4.1.8**  and running it using a console application.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        try
        {

            var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionstring");
            factory.PrefetchCount = 1;
            var queue = factory.CreateMessageReceiver("test");
            var options = new OnMessageOptions()
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                AutoComplete = false

            };
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            queue.OnMessageAsync(HandleMessageReceived, options);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception caught" + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }


    }
```

and this is my message handler

```
   async static Task HandleMessageReceived(BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)
    {

        try
        {


            await brokeredMessage.CompleteAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Message Processing completed");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Handlet exception" + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("has hit the catch of message handler ");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

After Starting the application and it completes few messages from test queue i go to portal and regenerate  my primary keys.

[image]

Comment: @Sean Feldman i guess you might be able to help me with this